# Variable let, problemas de compatibilidad con Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Tengo un proyecto donde en los distintos `js` que tenemos se mezclan variables de tipo `let` y `var`.

Aunque se declaren unas u otras, funcionan perfectamente en `Firefox` y `Chrome`, pero en Internet Explorer fallan.

Por lo que estuve leyendo por la red, let no fue una variable que soportara todos los navegadores, y se fue actualizando poco a poco para ser compatible con todos.

Incluso en en este hilo de stackoverflow se plantea una pregunta similar a la que ahora yo realizo [¿Que navegadores soportan la variable let?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356830/what-browsers-currently-support-javascripts-let-keyword)

Y dan soluciones de compatibilidad por ejemplo para `Chrome`.

Si lo cierto es que esos pequeños fallos que vemos de que las variables `let` en distintas versiones de `InternetExplorer` se pierden, vemos que en las más actuales esto no siempre sucede.

- ¿Para solucionar estos problemas es mejor declarar todas las variables
  a `let` o a `var`?
- ¿Puede afectar que estas variables se mezclen?
- ¿Que buenas prácticas debemos tener en cuenta para declarar variables en javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución posible es usar algo llamado babel, este traduce ordenes de javascript que estén dadas en una referencia mayor a ES5 el cuál  era compatible con internet explorer casi en su totalidad, es decir que cualquier cosa que sea de ES6 babel lo convierte primero a ES5 y en vez de usar el archivo original (Que tal vez tenga unas cosas de ES6), usas el archivo compilado por babel.

de hecho si deseas, dependiendo de en el navegador que te encuentres, puedes crear una etiqueta script directamente en el html y en esta condicional se pregunte si un elemento propio de ES6 por ejemplo existe, si existe significa que el navegador es compatible con ES6 y no requerimos usar el código compilado por babel, entonces en este script creamos otra etiqueta con un src que tendrá como ruta el script original (El que no fue compilado por babel).

De no ser así y ese elemento no existe puede significar o que el navegador esta muy desactualizado o que simplemente no es compatible, entonces hacemos lo mismo, creamos una etiqueta script desde javascript, le añadimos un src con referencia (Esta vez a la ruta del archivo compilado por babel), y nos libramos de este problema.

un ejemplo sería este:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <title>La pagina</title>

          <script>

           var scriptCargar;

               if($){

                    scriptCargar = document.createElement("script");
                    script.src = "/rutaDondeTienesElArchivo ES6.js";
                    document.body.appendChild(scriptCargar);

               }else{

                    scriptCargar = document.createElement("script");
                    scriptCargar.type = "text/javascript";
                    scriptCargar.src = "/Ruta del archivo compilado por babel.js";
                    document.body.appendChild(scriptCargar);

               }

          </script>

     </head>

     //Resto de elementos

</html>
```

En youtube hay una pequeña introducción a como se usa babel, la verdad me pareció muy practico para evitar este tipo de problemas de compatibilidad entre las versiones de javascript y los navegadores.

Con respecto a las preguntas propuestas entonces:

- ¿Para solucionar estos problemas es mejor declarar todas las variables a let o a var?

R// Si usas babel no importa cual tipo de variable declares si usas el archivo compilado por babel, en caso de que no uses babel, entonces eso dependerá de tu como usuario y creador a la vez si quieres o no darle soporte también a navegadores tan atrasados y problemáticos como internet explorer, en mi caso yo casi nunca doy soporte a este tipo de navegadores, pero si de verdad deseas hacer compatible casi cualquier versión de cualquier navegador con tu código, entonces lastimosamente no vale solo con decirte: "siempre utiliza var".

ya que esta no es la única instrucción que varia, si no que por ejemplo internet explorer en sus versiones mas viejas (Y puede que ahora todavía), hace uso de nombres de funciones con nombres diferentes un ejemplo es attachEvent(), que es la versión primitiva y casi descontinuada usada por internet explorer de lo que conocemos hoy en día como addEventListener, esto quiere decir que si le quieres dar compatibilidad manual por ti mismo a un navegador así, no solamente debes usar var siempre si no que debes aprenderte el equivalente a la función con nombre especial y que hace exactamente lo mismo de navegadores como internet explorer y usar siempre esas en vez de las actuales, de otra forma navegadores como estos no las reconocerán.

- ¿Puede afectar que estas variables se mezclen?

R// Depende de la compatibilidad del navegador con cada una de estas, como let y const por ejemplo son variables relativamente nuevas probablemente internet explorer no tiene aún compatibilidad con estas, así que se podría decir que si afecta... sin embargo en navegadores actualizados y que sean compatibles con ES6, NO IMPORTA, que variable uses, ya sea var, const o let, puedes usar las que desees y mezclarlas y no pasa nada el código sigue funcionando igual.

- ¿Que buenas prácticas debemos tener en cuenta para declarar variables en javascript?

R//

- Diferenciar variables globales de variables locales y ordenarlas de manera adecuada en el código (Que no estén esparcidas por todo el código si no que se encuentren en una parte en especial todas las que sean globales), así no solo serán mas fáciles de encontrar, si no que permite que el código se vea un poco mas organizado, normalmente estas variables globales se definen siempre al inicio de todo el código.
- Siempre que podamos, usar const en vez de var o let si el valor de una variable nunca va a cambiar en navegadores actualizados o compatibles, (Esto para poder asegurar la integridad del valor que tendrá nuestra constante).
- En navegadores actualizados y compatibles tratar de siempre declarar las variables con let y no con var, esto debido a que let tiene un acceso mas restringido que var, haciendo inalcanzable e imposible algunas "reescrituras" de una variable sin querer, es decir, en teoría es mas seguro utilizar let que var para también de cierto modo "salvaguardar" la integridad de nuestra variable y que no sea reescrita sin querer.

Comment: Adjunto enlace de la documentación de babel https://babeljs.io/docs/en/

Comment: preguntas basadas en opiniones o mal formuladas no se deben responder mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)